# Regex help in JavaScript to validate and extract last number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking to validate an input text against the following pattern in JS/JQuery:
`P-1-A100`
or

`R-5-M42`
or 
`P-10-B99`, etc

The text essentially needs to have the following six parts:

1. Single character P or R followed by
2. A single '-' followed by
3. Any number with 1 or more digits followed by
4. A single '-' followed by
5. Any alphabet (A-Z) followed by
6. Any number with 1 or more digits.

Do I need to take care of escape characters as well. 
How do I make sure that the input text matches the regular expression.

If it does match, how can I extract the last part (Number)from the input text.
I have tried this, but isn't working for me

`var isMatch = inputText.match([PR]-\d+-[A-Z]+\d+)`

Comment: Perhaps, [`/^[PR]-\d+-[A-Z]+(\d+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/tV4iM3/1)? Use a capturing group around the subpattern that your are interested in getting from the text.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/t1g566a0/

Comment: That worked like a charm!Thanks Wiktor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add group to your regex.

```
var match = inputText.match(/^[PR]-\d+-[A-Z]+(\d+)$/);
```

If match is not null, then number will be in array on position `match[1]`.

```
var number = match ? match[1] : null;
```

EDIT:
Added anchors as  Aaron suggested.